# copying first 3 columns from different worksheets to single files

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I have a bunch of datasets with always the same worksheets.

Now I want to make a different file for each worksheet. I found some code that does just that: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/628-excel-split-workbook.html#kutools

However, I also only want the first three columns of those worksheets and preferably always starting from row 2.

Could somebody point me in the right direction. E.g. on how to change the code I posted.

Comment: I don't see code in that link, I just see a Ribbon managed addin.  It wouldn't be too hard to do this with VBA.

Comment: Let me point you to Alt + F11, VBA at your disposal. Now as you are a programmer (as StackOVerflow is a platform for programmers) I expect you to be able to code, with that in mind please consider using the record macro button from the Excel spreadsheet window to record the activities you would want to code. Stop recording and switch to your VBA window to see the result and work with that to automate what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Sub Splitbook()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim myPath As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim wkb As Workbook

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        lastRow = sht.Range("A6500").End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow < 2 Then GoTo nextSht

        Set rng = sht.Range("A2:C" & lastRow)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
            rng.Copy wkb.Sheets(1).Range("A2")
            myPath = filePath(sht.Name)
            wkb.SaveAs Filename:=myPath
            wkb.Close
            Set wkb = Nothing
            Set rng = Nothing
        End If

nextSht:
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function filePath(worksheetname As String) As String

    Dim fso As Object, MyFolder As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    MyFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Reports"


    If fso.FolderExists(MyFolder) = False Then
        fso.CreateFolder (MyFolder)
    End If

    MyFolder = MyFolder & "\" & Format(Now(), "MMM_YYYY")
    If fso.FolderExists(MyFolder) = False Then
        fso.CreateFolder (MyFolder)
    End If


    filePath = MyFolder & "\" & worksheetname & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY hh.mm.ss") & ".xlsx"
    Set fso = Nothing

End Function
```